# Trouble seeing why this is the dual of an LP

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

$A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. Using the notation $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, $z=(z_1, \ldots, z_m)$, and $y=(y_1, \ldots, y_m)$, I'm reading that if the primal LP is

$$
\min 0x_1 + 0x_2 + \cdots + 0x_n + z_1 + z_2 + \cdots +z_m
$$
s.t.
$$
Ax +z\ge \mathbf{1};\\
z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_m \ge 0.
$$

then the dual LP is

$$
\max y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_m$$

s.t.

$$
A^Ty = \mathbf{0}\\
0 \le y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m \le 1
$$

I don't see where the constraint $A^Ty = 0$ in the dual is coming from. Shouldn't it be $A^Ty \le 0$ ? Or are these constraints somehow equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should just derive it from first principles. The Lagrangian is
$$L(x,z,y,w) = \mathbf{1}^T z - y^T ( Ax + z - \mathbf{1} ) - w^T z$$
where $y$ and $w$ are my two Lagrange multipliers. The dual problem is
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & g(y,w)\triangleq \inf_{x,z} L(x,z,y,w) \\
\text{subject to} & y,w \succeq \mathbf{0} \end{array}$$
In order to get a better expression for $g(y,w)$, I differentiate $L$ with respect 
to $x$ and $z$, revealing two equations:
$$- A^T y = \mathbf{0}, \quad \mathbf{1} - y - w = \mathbf{0}$$
If either these conditions are not met, the dual function $g(y,w)=\inf_{x,z} L(x,z,y,w)$ is unbounded below. So these are the implicit dual equality constraints. Making those equations explicit yields a cleaned-up dual problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & y^T \mathbf{1} \\
\text{subject to} & A y = \mathbf{0} \\ & y + w = \mathbf{1} \\ & y,w \succeq \mathbf{0} \end{array}$$
Eliminating $w$ gives us
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & y^T \mathbf{1} \\
\text{subject to} & A y = \mathbf{0} \\ & y \preceq \mathbf{1} \\ & y\succeq \mathbf{0} \end{array}$$
which is exactly what you are reading.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to see this without the use of Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Perhaps, but I can't see how, nor do I see *why*. These are the very underpinnings of LP duality here. It would do you well to understand things at this level, not try an concoct a list of ad-hoc high-level rules for constructing the dual. For one thing, if you master this, then constructing the dual of an arbitrarily-structured LP will be a piece of cake.

Comment: You can say this: your primal problem has $2m$ inequalities and/or slack variables, so your dual problem should have exactly the same number. That's covered by the two inequalities on $y$.

Comment: I think another way to get at it is to start with $A^Ty=0$ version as the primal and see that you get essentially the same dual as my original primal. But this is probably what your hinting at with the $2m$ inequalities...

Comment: Well sure, if you know both problems you can come up with all sorts of principles to explain how they can be related by duality. But most of the time you have only one and need the other; and in practice few models assume a tidy standard form. Learn the mechanics of finding the dual! It will serve you well.